# DateTime.ParseExact: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to get the date (& datetime) from the url and then convert it into its proper format before storing it in the db.

```
var reqDate = Request.QueryString["StartDate"];

//at this point I have reqDate: 05/15/2018 00:00:00
reqDate = reqDate.Substring(0, reqDate.IndexOf(" ") + 1);

//after stripping off the time part I have: 05/15/2018 
timingRequest.ReqDate = DateTime.ParseExact(reqDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//but this throws the exception
```

URL:

[image]

Same is the case with `startDateTime`

```
var reqDateTime = Request.QueryString["startDateTime"];
 timingRequest.IgnoreEntry = DateTime.ParseExact(reqDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy  hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Instead of using asp-classic style QueryString parsing, why not just add `DateTime StartDate` as a parameter to your MVC Controller method? That way the default model binder will do all the hard work for you?

Comment: parse exact mean exactly that. the first example you have the space still in the date sub string while in the second you have two spaces between date and time.

Comment: Looks like it using different date format: `timingRequest.IgnoreEntry = DateTime.ParseExact(reqDateTime, "MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. However I recommend to use session state instead of query strings to store `DateTime`.

Comment: @Nkosi how do I strip off those spaces?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto what about the first scenario?

Comment: Because `reqDate = reqDate.Substring(0, reqDate.IndexOf(" ") + 1);` gives you an extra space at the end -  `"05/15/2018 "`, not `"05/15/2018"`

Comment: first scenario `reqDate = reqDate.Substring(0, reqDate.IndexOf(" "));`

Comment: @StephenMuecke 2 quickies, how'd you find out that it has a trailing space? and second how do I remove it?

Comment: See @Nkosi comment

Comment: Perfect and second scenario?

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar while appreciated, you don't need my permission to write an answer. go ahead.

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar take note the time format is `HH:mm:ss`

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar, If you are going to add an answer, tell OP to stop that nonsense, and add parameters `DateTime startDate, DateTime startDateTime` to the method and let the `DefaultModelBinder` do its job

Comment: @StephenMuecke how do I do it with model binding?

Comment: You would need to include the parameters in  the action definition.

Comment: Just add those parameters to your method - `public ActionResult Create(DateTime startDate, DateTime startDateTime)` and you can also add parameters for the other values - `int empID` and `int attID` - the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind them

Comment: Is this a GET or POST request. This question appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Nkosi Post request, I want to do the better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Example fix:

```
var reqDate = Request.QueryString["StartDate"];
reqDate = reqDate.Substring(0, reqDate.IndexOf(" "));

timingRequest.ReqDate = DateTime.ParseExact(reqDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Second Example Fix:

```
var reqDateTime = Request.QueryString["startDateTime"];
 timingRequest.IgnoreEntry = DateTime.ParseExact(reqDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first scenario, No need to add +1 after reading `indexOf(" ")`. +1 adding extra space to date

```
//Lets take date in string is "05/15/2018 00:00:00"
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, reqDate.IndexOf(" ")+1)); /*This will print "05/15/2018 " WITH EXTRA SPACE*/
```

Correct way is `s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(" "))`

In second scenario, use date format like `HH:mm:ss` instead of `HH:mm tt`

```
//Here use "hh:mm:ss" instead of "hh:mm tt"
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(reqDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy  hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

Elegant approach would be:

@Credit Stephen Muecke

After looking at your URL, you can write a method having parameters like,

```
public ActionResult Create(int empId, int attID, DateTime startDate, DateTime startDateTime)
{
 /*Do your work here, DefaultModelBinder will take care of parameters*/
}
```